# Subsetting columns of an R matrix contingent on a specific entry

Tags: r, matrix, subset

It seems as though this question should have been asked a bunch of times, but I'm searching the `Questions that may already have your answer` without success.

**How do you subset with Boolean operators (without using `subset()`) the columns of a matrix?**

```
> m = matrix(c("A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "A", "C", "C", "D"), nrow = 3)
> m
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] "A"  "B"  "C" 
[2,] "B"  "C"  "C" 
[3,] "B"  "A"  "D"
```

Notice that the columns have no names, and I want **any** columns that contain in some entry the value "D".

For instance, in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27755737/4089351), the call `grades[grades[,"pass"] == 2,]`. Aside from the fact that the call is to extract rows, and the fact that `pass` refers to a single column, there are no names for the columns.

I have tried:

```
> m[m == "D", ]
Error in m[m == "D", ] : (subscript) logical subscript too long

> m[which(m=="D"), ]
Error in m[which(m == "D"), ] : subscript out of bounds

> m = as.data.frame(m) # Turning the matrix into a df
> m[m == "D", ]
     V1   V2   V3
NA <NA> <NA> <NA>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an alternative.

```
m[, colSums(m == "D") > 0, drop=FALSE]
     [,1]
[1,] "C" 
[2,] "C" 
[3,] "D"
```

`m==D` constructs a logical matrix, then `colSums` counts the number of TRUEs. Next, these are checked as to whether any are greater than 0. The result of this check is used to subset the matrix. Following @cdeterman's answer, I added drop=FALSE to preserve the matrix structure.

Comment: Really elegant! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use an `apply` call to search the column elements and index on those.

```
m[,apply(m, MARGIN = 2, function(x) any(x == "D")), drop = FALSE]

     [,1]
[1,] "C" 
[2,] "C" 
[3,] "D"
```

Note - you will notice `drop = FALSE` argument is present.  This is to make sure the output is still a matrix in the event there is only 1 column.

Comment: Thank you. This is one painful way of subsetting it. Please don't misread this as a criticism, because you may very well be correct - R is not particularly easy... `MARGIN = 2` introduces the concept that we want columns?

Comment: Correct, `MARGIN` indicates if over rows or columns.  You can see this in the documentation.

Comment: @Toni, also if this satisfies your question please be sure to accept this answer.